# Как создать гиф картинку с части видео?

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, gif

Хочу создать генератор *gif*-ок из видео (как локального видео, так и из ссылки на *youtube*), с возможность задания части видео с которого нужно будет делать *gif*ку нашел несколько *js*-библиотек, но они могут создавать только с локального видео-файла и не могут вырезать часть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть какие-то готовые библиотеки/решения (*php*, *javascript*) или сам принцип решения.

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаем палитру:

   ```
   ffmpeg -y -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv \
   -vf fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen palette.png
   ```
2. Формируем гифку с испльзованием палитры:

   ```
   ffmpeg -ss 30 -t 3 -i input.flv -i palette.png -filter_complex \
   "fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif
   ```

Еще больше примеров можно найти тут: http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Библиотека gifshot [ссылка](http://yahoo.github.io/gifshot)
2. Библиотека FFmpeg -> [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.B8_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.8B)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101543/how-to-make-gif-image-from-youtube-video